# How does java generics syntax help avoid type casting?

Tags: java, generics, javac

Below is the code,

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lst = new  ArrayList<String>();
        lst.add("a string");
        lst.add("another string");
        String s = lst.get(0);
    } //end main
}
```

when the constructor `new  ArrayList<String>();` is invoked, array of type `Object` is created.

[image]
..

`lst` holds `Object[0]` array.

[image]

So, If array of type `Object` gets created by constructor, How does `javac` does not see type casting issue in this statement `String s = lst.get(0);`, despite generic syntax is used while invoking constructor?

Comment: That's the point of generics: the compiler adds the cast to the byte-code for you, and makes sure that this cast has no way to fail, thanks to the generic type of the list.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/juneau-generics-2255374.html

Comment: @JBNizet Except `LocalVariableTypeTable` attrbute in the byte code that has  entry: `8      30     1   lst   Ljava/util/List<Ljava/lang/String;>;` for generic enabled syntax, both scenarios looks same from byte code perspective, functionally.

Comment: That's what I said: the compiler does the type checking, and adds casts for you in the code. At runtime, it basically works the same way as without generics.

Comment: @JBNizet this line is available in both scenarios: `33: checkcast     #33                 // class java/lang/String`.

Comment: There's a cast in this client code right after the get returns.

Comment: @chrylis For non-generic code `Object obj = lst.get(0);` I do not see `checkcast` byte code instruction after `get` returns. JB Nizet is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some non-generic code:

```
public class MyList {

    List myData = new ArrayList();

    public void add(Object ob) {
        myData.add(ob);
    }

    public Object getAtIndex(int ix) {
        return myData.get(ix);
    }
}
```

This code will allow you to store an object of any type into your MyList instances **even if** the contract of MyList specifies that the objects must all be of the same type.  Moreover if you use a MyList instance to store String instances, you must manually cast them to String when you retrieve them.

```
String myString = (String) myList.get(1);
```

The above MyList class is not type safe.  It is most definitely possible that the above assignment statement will fail with a ClassCastException if an object other than a String instance was stored into your MyList instance (which can happen at run-time without any complaint).

Here is a generified MyList class:

```
public class MyList<T> {

    List<T> myData = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(T ob) {
        myData.add(ob);
    }

    public T getAtIndex(int ix) {
        return myData.get(ix);
    }
}
```

Now, the compiler guarantees that only `T` instances can be added and retrieved from MyList instances.  Because the compiler guarantees that `T` instances will always be returned, you can use syntax like this without any manual casting:

```
String myString = myList.get(1);
```

The generified MyList class is now type-safe.  The compiler won't allow you to store anything but `T` instances into your MyList instances, which guarantees that no ClassCastExceptions will occur at run-time.  If you examine the byte-code, you'll find that the compiler has placed a cast automatically.

Generics in Java are a **compile-time only** phenomenon.  In the byte-code, all references to `T` in the MyList class above are replaced by `Object`.  This process is referred to as "type erasure".  It is important to remember that type safety in Java is provided by the compiler only.  If your program compiles without any errors **AND** without any warnings, then your program, generics and all, is type safe.  The compiled program, however, has retained almost no information about the generic parameters.

Comment: Although a correct overview, this actually does not answer the question, why there is no type-casting needed when retrieving elements from the list, despite the fact that the internal array in `ArrayList` is of type `Object[]`.

Comment: In successfully compiled generic code, the compiler will have automatically inserted a cast from type Object (or from a bounded type).  One will need to examine the byte-code in order to see this cast.  It does not need to present in the source code because the compiler has already assured that the assignment is type safe.

Comment: No, there simply is an explicit cast in the source code of `ArrayList`. See @chrylis's answer for that. OP's question did not ask for the usage of a generic type (I assume he knows that); he asked about an internal detail of `ArrayList`.

Comment: There is no requirement for an explicit cast in generic source code and it is almost always omitted.

Comment: Maybe I cannot clearly express me, but you still are on the wrong path: OP is not asking how to use a generic type for which there is indeed no cast required. He asked about an internal detail of `ArrayList`. Look at the question again. He asked, why there is no cast needed, although the internal array is of type `Object[]`! The answer: Because the `get` method does this cast (and this is an explicit cast)!

Comment: The question I answered was the one which the OP asked which is *"How does java generics syntax help avoid type casting?"*  You seem to be asking about the issues related to generifying a class that contains an array internally.  Generics and arrays do not mix well in Java as you know.  I regard this as a separate question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83016/discussion-between-seelenvirtuose-and-scottb).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose the cast inside the ArrayList code is useful for the compiler only. It doesn't do anything at runtime, because T is actually Object at runtime. What matters is the cast added by the compiler when getting a T from the list as a T. Execute this gist: the first test will pass fine, but the second won't: https://gist.github.com/jnizet/e0381dec9fbf05f269d7

Comment: @scottb so, lowerbounds/upperbounds/wildcards concept of generics are helping the compiler to add explicit cast bytecode instruction. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

From farther down in the class:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}

public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}
```

That `@SuppressWarnings` tells the compiler that you're sure about the unchecked cast that you're performing there. Since all of the other operations, such as `get(int)`, use the type parameter `E`, this restricts the unsafe type handling to specific locations where the implementer can make sure to handle the cast correctly.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment, especially since the downvote came in too fast for the voter to have possibly read the answer?